# What's a good, free, drop-in set of mimetype icons?

Tags: icons, mime-types

I want a set of mimetype icons to go with my file uploads, to show in users' files lists and the like.

It should be:

- 16x16 PNG or JPG (other sizes through 64x64 would be a bonus but not required)
- already organized such that I can do e.g. mimetype.sub('/','-') + '.png' and get the icon file name (I'd like to avoid spending a bunch of time figuring out the associations)
- not platform specific, preferably using properitary apps' native icons where available (e.g. a .zip icon should not look like a KDE box)
- pretty but readable and suitable to a general audience ;-)

What's a good package for this?

Comment: The challenge is finding some of the proprietary ones like the Microsoft Office suite and the Adobe Creative Suite, for starters. Most of the open source stuff is duplicated across most of the big open source libraries. See this post for a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298518/where-can-i-find-good-mimetype-icons

Answer (score 8):

I found these: http://openiconlibrary.sourceforge.net/gallery2/?./Icons/mimetypes/oxygen-style

Edit 14-09-09 15:14 the link is now dead.

I don't know anymore how the above looked but I like these too: https://github.com/pasnox/oxygen-icons-png/tree/master/oxygen

Answer (score 4):

I like [Silk Icons](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/). They contain over 700  16-by-16 pixel icons in strokably-soft PNG format and licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 License.

Answer (score 2):

Given [the sheer volume of mime types](http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp) out there, I think it's unlikely that you'll find a collection which encompasses all of them.

For a reasonable subset, what about [Crystal Clear](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Crystal_Clear_mimetype_icons)? The mime types aren't handed to you on a plate, but it should be reasonably easy to spot which ones map to where I would think?

Answer (score 2):

there is an open source project :
https://github.com/teambox/Free-file-icons
it came in handy for me. when creating my file manger ..

it support 4 sizes (16,32,48,512) along with good naming [uniformed]
add to that the an .ai file came with it in case you wish to edit.

Answer (score 2):

I've been hunting for such an icon set, but all of the ones I've found have some reason not to use them (usually missing MIME types for Office 2007+ formats).

However, I stumbled across this [WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mimetypes-link-icons/) which has a great set of icons in a number of sizes with standardized naming (based on file extension).

I know they can't be used directly with MIME types, but it's generally not too difficult to extend a system to support file extensions.

Edit: I don't use WordPress... just the icons.